# Python вызов функции из функции того же класса

Tags: python, классы, функции, методы

Ломаю голову не понимаю чего он от меня хочет:

`TypeError: date_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

```
import random

class format_creator:
    def random_string(self, string):
        return string[random.randint(0,len(string)-1)]
    def date_generator(self):
        hashtag_on_off = ('', '#')
        result = self.random_string(hashtag_on_off)
        return result
```

Прошу выручайте друзья!

```
import presets_generator #название файла с проблемным классом
preset = presets_generator.format_creator
result = preset.date_generator()
print(result)

TypeError: date_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Вот так я вызываю данный метод через объект класса в другом файле. Получаю ту же ошибку. Понимаю что ошибка именно в том что я как то не правильно вызываю функцию из функции одного и того же класса

Comment: В классе не должно быть такого кода вне методов. Если из другого метода вызывать, то `self.date_generator()`.

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите сделать то? Создать класс со статическими функциями? Почему у вас нет конструктора? Экземпляры не будут создаваться?

Comment: @insolor спасибо что откликнулся. Уточню проблему: 
    print(date_generator())   здесь для примера-удалил. При вызове данной функции из основной программы так же получаю "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". Одним словом, не могу вызвать random_string() из date_generator()

Comment: Вызов функций класса (методов) всегда через объект или через класс.

Comment: @suit, конструктор не требуется. Нужен набор функций просто. Мне нужно вызвать random_string() из date_generator(). Вот здесь и получаю ошибку с self. вызываю данный класс и его метод date_generator() из основного кода.

Comment: @insolor
import presets_generator
preset = presets_generator.format_creator
result = preset.date_generator()
print(result)

Вот так я вызываю данный метод через объект класса в другом файле. Получаю ту же ошибку. Понимаю что ошибка именно в том что я как то не правильно вызываю функцию из функции одного и того же класса

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @insolor исправился, добавил

Comment: @insolor self пробовал добавлять даже перед hashtag_on_off. Пробовал вытаскивать hashtag_on_off из функции в класс. Все одно и то же получаю...

Comment: @suit, если конструктора нет, то будет использоваться родительский, т.е. экземпляры будут созданы

Comment: Либо можно создать экземпляр `preset = presets_generator.format_creator()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужен класс со вспомогательными функциями, то методы лучше делать статичными:

```
class format_creator:

    @staticmethod
    def random_string(string):
        return string[random.randint(0,len(string)-1)]

    @classmethod
    def date_generator(cls):
        hashtag_on_off = ('', '#')
        result = cls.random_string(hashtag_on_off)
        return result
```

`classmethod` нужен для того, чтобы можно было обращаться из этого метода к другим методам этого класса. Если этого не требуется, то все методы следует сделать `staticmethod`.

Вызов:

```
result = format_creator.date_generator()
print(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо, боги #stackoverflow за помощь. и @suit за очень понятное объяснение механик!